# Predicate Calculus - Resolution

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

A question came up at the our schools logic club this week which involves using resolution to prove an argument in predicate calculus. I am slightly aware of how to find prenex normal forms but to actually solve the question I am having some difficulty. The question is as follows:

Use resolution for predicate calculus to prove that the argument below
is valid. (find the prenex normal forms of the required formulas, then the ∃-free prenex normal forms, transform them into clauses and perform resolution). Describe in details all your work.

```
Premise 1: ∃x(P(x) ∧ ¬Q(x, a))
Premise 2: ∃x[P(x) ∧ ∀y(P(y) ∧ R(x, y) → Q(y, a))]
Conclusion: ∃x∃y(P(x) ∧ P(y) ∧ ¬R(x, y))
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: How about using truth trees?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

The prenex normal forms are trivial; thus we can go directly to the "elimination" of $\exists$.

From *Premise 1* we get :

> $P(b) \land \lnot Q(b,a)$

and from *Premise 2* we get :

> $P(c) \land [\lnot P(y) \lor \lnot R(c,y) \lor Q(y,a)]$.

Thus, we have 4 *clauses* :

1) $P(b)$

2) $\lnot Q(b,a)$

3) $P(c)$

4) $\lnot P(y) \lor \lnot R(c,y) \lor Q(y,a)$.

Then we add the negation of the *Conclusion*, which is again a *clause* :

6) $\lnot P(x) \lor \lnot P(y) \lor R(x, y)$.

Now we have to perform [Resolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_%28logic%29), starting from 1) and 3) with the unifiers :

> $b \to y$ and $c \to x$.